# Pass information from Windows Form Text box to Get-ChildItem Or something similar

Tags: winforms, powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a directory of music that I created a GUI in Powershell to display and select certain songs. 
The problem is the directory contains over 1,000 songs, so I want to be able to search the directory from the Windows Form I wrote. I wrote every part I needed, the only thing I can't do is get the auto complete to work properly. 
When I try to run the script, a window pops up that says
 `Unhandled exception has occurred in a component in your application. If you click Continue, the application will ignore this error and attempt to continue. Specified cast is not valid.` 

Included is the appropriate code (I left out the Go and Cancel buttons, along with a label, for brevity's sake). What am I missing?

Code:

```
# Dependencies
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 

# Form Skeleton
$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$objForm.Text = "Select a Song"
$objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400,300) 
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

# Use Enter/Escape in addition to GO/Cancel
$objForm.KeyPreview = $True
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter") 
     {$UserInput=$objListBox.SelectedItem;$objForm.Close()}})
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") 
    {$objForm.Close()}})

# Search Bar    
$objTextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$objTextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,40) 
$objTextBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,160)
$objTextBox.Text = "Search..." 
$objTextBox.AutoCompleteSource = 'CustomSource'
$objTextBox.AutoCompleteMode='SuggestAppend'
$objTextBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource=$autocomplete
$objForm.Controls.Add($objTextBox) 

# Box the files appear in
$objListBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox 
$objListBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(40,70) 
$objListBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) 
$objListBox.Height = 150

# Listing the songs in the directory
Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\adammcgurk\Desktop\Songs' | % {$objTextBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange($_) }
$objForm.Controls.Add($objTextBox) 

# Just some style
$objForm.Topmost = $True

$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})
[void] $objForm.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 1):

*Note: The following works in PSv5.1, but not in PSv2. PSv2 compatibility is what the OP needs.*

Replace:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\adammcgurk\Desktop\Songs' | 
  % {$objTextBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange($_) }
```

with this:

```
($autocomplete = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteStringCollection).
  AddRange((Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\adammcgurk\Desktop\Songs' | % { $_.Name }))
$objTextBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = $autocomplete
```

The above is merely a more efficient variation of the OP's own code (assuming that the OP actually initialized his `$autocomplete` variable to a `[System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteStringCollection]` instance).

It **doesn't work in v2** for two reasons:

- syntactically: placing whitespace between member accessor `.` and the member name (`AddRange`) breaks in v2 - that's easily remedied by removing that whitespace, however.
- more importantly, **presumably due to a bug**, passing the `[System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteStringCollection]` to `$objForm.Controls.Add` *breaks* due to an unavailable COM interface, it seems. [Interacting with the COM types directly](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3792/C-does-Shell-Part) - which is much more cumbersome - may offer a solution.